# Current in Photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Experimentally, the current is saturated at negative values when reaching the stopping potential (as in the first photo) Theoretically, current is saturated at zero (as in second graph) why is that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1 pA is a tiny current, not unreasonable as "dark current" of some sort, not photocurrent. "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice they are different."

Answer (score 1):

If I got your plots right, if you zoom on the second picture in the region close to the stopping potential, and include the branch at negative current, you'd find the trend of the first picture. For a full plot,

[image]

Comment: what do circles and triangles represent?

Comment: Maybe ratio of a reference light intensity at the given wavelength. Just a hint, because the original paper is not open-source